# How to throw an error with Asymptote?

Tags: asymptote

In Asymptote programming, how to throw an error? I tried `error("message")` but the argument of the `error` function is a file, not a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an `assert` command that might work for you.  `void assert(bool b, string s="");`

So the following code: `assert(false, "My Error Message");`

Will abort execution with the following statement at the command line. `assert FAILED: My Error Message`

There's also `void exit();` that exits with a zero error return code.

And `void abort(string s="")` returns a non-zero code and prints the string.